# Networking rotation sync

Tags: rotation, frame-rate, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

My Unity version is 5.2.3f1, I m trying to sync the rotation of a child gameobject, in local works perfectly fine but it doesnt show up in other clients. I tried everything I could find and nothing.

The reason of this is to rotate a FPS body, so, I m trying to rotate Spine2 (Rotate the camera is not my best solution). I m using a Mixamo character to test, in the end I will have Mixamo auto-rigged charscters so everything I make here will be compatible.

I tried to use the Network Transform Rigidbody 3D and it only sync the character itself, not Spine2, I have tried Network Transform Child, and an official skeleton sync.

In the script part, I have tried a lot of things, the most promising one was this:

```
 [SyncVar]
 private Quaternion syncPlayerRotation;
 [SerializeField]
 private Transform playerTransform;
 [SerializeField]
 private float lerpRate = 15f;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void LateUpdate () {
     TransmitRotations();
     LerpRotations();
 }
 void LerpRotations()
 {
     if (!isLocalPlayer)
     playerTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(playerTransform.localRotation, syncPlayerRotation, Time.deltaTime * lerpRate);
 }
 [Command]
 void CmdProvideRotationsToServer(Quaternion playerRot)
 {
     syncPlayerRotation = playerRot;
 }

 [Client]
 void TransmitRotations()
 {
     if (isLocalPlayer)
     {
         CmdProvideRotationsToServer(playerTransform.localRotation);
     }
 }
```

Its from UNET tutorial series on youtube, Gamer To Game Developer user.

I attached it to Spine2 and still dont work, but when I attached it to the main character, it worked.

Also tried this:

```
 void OnSerializeNetworkView(BitStream stream, NetworkMessageInfo info)
 {
     Vector3 syncPosition = Vector3.zero;
     if (stream.isWriting)
     {
         syncPosition = Spine.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position;
         stream.Serialize(ref syncPosition);
     }
     else
     {
         stream.Serialize(ref syncPosition);
         Spine.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = syncPosition;
     }
 }
```

But I think it was for an older version of Unity.

To make the rotations I m using [A Free Simple Smooth Mouselook](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/a-free-simple-smooth-mouselook.73117/)

I edited it, this lines:

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
         {
             var xRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-_mouseAbsolute.y, targetOrientation * Vector3.forward);
             transform.localRotation = xRotation;

         }
         else
         {
             var xRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-_mouseAbsolute.y, targetOrientation * Vector3.right);
             transform.localRotation = xRotation;
         }
```

Basicly, I changed Vector3.right to Vector3.forward and converted the Vector3.right only if the right mouse button is not pressed. The script is attached to Spine2 and its activated on the start if(isLocalPlayer) by script.

There's a pic of the current hierarchy:

[image]

(some cameras are there only to test, the main camera is FirstPersonCamera, extracted from the standard assets)

I noticed that if I debug log the Spine2 rotation, it only gives me values from 0 to 1.